# How do I get TIMESTAMP whenever I add data into MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

How can I get timestamp when I add data using PHP in MySQL?

Comment: If you repeat the question 7 more times it happens automatically

Answer (score 3):

You can set Default value for your column is: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP so when new record be added it have get current timestamp on your server by automaticly.